# jquery ajaxStart and ajaxStop not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked all around but still couldnt get a solution for this problem.

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    jQuery('#fuzz-overlay').show();
    //alert('Showing');
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    jQuery('#fuzz-overlay').hide();
});
```

Here's the ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'admin.php',
        data: {
            action: "get_content"
        },
        global: true,
        async: false
    }).done(function(data){
        //...
    });
```

This works in modern browsers, but in IE it executes both ajaxStart and ajaxStop together, unless I place an alert box after `show()`. I've read that I need to place the `ajaxStart` functions before calling `$.ajax` but these functions get loaded before anything else.

Is there a solution? Perhaps some sort of `DoEvents` function that executes `ajaxStart` when it's supposed to?

Comment: By setting `async` to `false`, your request is no longer an AJAX request.

Comment: You're not doing anything asynchronous, you sort of turned of the functionality that is the entire point of ajax ?

Comment: turning it off still doesnt solve the problem

Comment: no,no! You have to turn it back on again ?

Comment: i used async because it was used in a function that returned a value. it does work with async set to true, but now the function doesnt return a value

Comment: It returns a value, when it's done. You have to code "around" the asynchronous nature of ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function to do the same task when ajax is over, you may use jquery or plain javascript for this. That may work in old browsers.

Comment: i have multiple ajax function calls and i would prefer if i wouldn't have to write the code for each one and instead just have a global handler for ajax loader

Comment: when you say it works in modern browsers I can't believe you actually see the background change for the duration of the call do you ? as indicated above you need to make the request async to get it to behave as you expect.